# Strange issue on image hover

Tags: html, css

I´m doing an effect on mouse image hover, but I´m having a problem.

I have 3 articles and When I hover an image all the other images are moving to the right.

I found that the problem is here: .second-effect:hover a.info{}, because if I remove the    `transform:scale(1,1)` when I hover the image other images dont move.

But Without this transform my icon font that I want to show in the center of the image don´t appears.

**The problem is here:**

```
.second-effect:hover a.info {
    opacity:1;
    -moz-transform:scale(1,1);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1,1);
    -o-transform:scale(1,1);
    -ms-transform:scale(1,1);
    transform:scale(1,1);
    -moz-transition-delay:0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-delay:0.3s;
    -o-transition-delay:0.3s;
    -ms-transition-delay:0.3s;
    transition-delay:0.3s;
}
```

So I want to have an icon font in center of my image inside the square that I´m doing with css transitions.

If I remove the `transform:scale(1,1)` the icon dont appears.

If I dont remove this code when I hover an image, the other images are also moving.

Can anyone understand why this is happening?

**My jsfiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ritz/m78QF/1/

**My whole html for this issue:**

```
 <article id="news">
    <div class="view second-effect">
        <img src="imagens/transferir (1).jpg" />
        <div class="mask">
            <a href="#" class="info"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
        </div>
     </div>
      <h2>
       <a>Title Post number one</a>
        <br />
     </h2>
     <span>Date of post number one</span> 
     <p>Post Number one</p>
</article>
```

**My Whole css for this issue:**

```
.info>i{font-size:1.7em; margin-top:15px; color:#000;  }

    #news img
    {
        width:155px;
        height:140px; 
    }

    .view a.info {

       padding:0;
       width:20px;
       height:20px;
    }

    .view {
       width: 155px;
       height: 140px;
       float: left;
       overflow: hidden;
       position: relative;
       text-align: center;
       box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #aaa;
       cursor: default;
       margin-right:20px; 
       border:3px solid #ccc;
       margin-top:4px;

    }
    .view .mask, .view .content {
        width: 155px;
       height: 140px;
       position: absolute;
       overflow: hidden;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
    }

    .view img {
       display: block;
       position: relative;
    }
    .view a.info>i{

    }    
    .second-effect .mask {
       opacity: 0;
       overflow:visible;
       border:0px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
       -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
       -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
       box-sizing:border-box;
       -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
       -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
       transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }
    .second-effect a.info {
        position:relative;
        top:-10px;
        opacity:0;
       -moz-transform:scale(0,0);
       -webkit-transform:scale(0,0);
       -o-transform:scale(0,0);
       -ms-transform:scale(0,0);
       transform:scale(0,0);
       -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s 0.1s ease-in, opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s 0.1s ease-in, opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: -o-transform 0.2s 0.1s ease-in, opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
       -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.2s 0.1s ease-in, opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
       transition: transform 0.2s 0.1s ease-in, opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
    }
    .second-effect:hover .mask {
       opacity: 1;
       border:55px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    }
    .second-effect:hover a.info {
        opacity:1;
        -moz-transform:scale(1,1);
        -webkit-transform:scale(1,1);
        -o-transform:scale(1,1);
        -ms-transform:scale(1,1);
        transform:scale(1,1);
        -moz-transition-delay:0.3s;
        -webkit-transition-delay:0.3s;
        -o-transition-delay:0.3s;
        -ms-transition-delay:0.3s;
        transition-delay:0.3s;
    }
```

Comment: I can't comment to this specific problem, but I notice you are assigning both `position: absolute;` and `position: relative;` to class `.view`. The latter property will override the former property, making it pointless. Also, why have a blank `.view a.info>i{}` selector? Wasting space there.

Comment: If your image already is positioned relatively, just give it a `bottom:5px`  this will lift it 5px from the bottom, or if you need it to adjust from the top, you can say `top:-5px`

Comment: Thanks but I want that the icon image go top 5px and not the image. I think I explained myself bad, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Adding `bottom: 5px;` to the `.view img` should achieve this.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m78QF/2/) width updated `.view img`

```
.view img {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   bottom: 5px
}
```

EDIT:
Change

```
.second-effect:hover .mask {
opacity: 1;
border: 55px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

to

```
.second-effect:hover .mask {
opacity: 1;
border: 55px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
padding-top: 36px;
}
```

It will made the white area of the transition a bit bigger.

Comment: I think I explain myself bad. I want to give margin-bottom to the icon and no the image. With that bottom:5px  my image is going up 5px but I want to go up the icon and not the image.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `icon font`?

Comment: I updat my question with an image with the problem I´m having. The icon font is the icon of download. Its like a icon but its made with fonts to dont overload the page with many images!

Comment: I´m formating the icon font here: .info>i{font-size:1.7em; margin-top:15px; color:#000;  }

Comment: From what is in the jsfiddle, (imo) it's quiet hard to move that icon since it can't be seen. Check my edit, it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Why does your CSS have a `margin-top` set? Would that not be pushing down your icon? Try commenting it out and see if it changes the icon's position. If it does, just reduce your `margin-top` and that should bring your icon into place.

```
.info>i
{
font-size:1.7em; 
/* margin-top:15px; */ 
color:#000; 
margin-bottom:5px; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have 4 news and the problem with that way is that When I hover an image with the mouse the other images move whenever I hover a Image.

Comment: And I found that the problem is in here: .second-effect:hover a.info {}. If I remove the transform:scale(1,1); I dont have that problem, but then the icon font disappear :S. I really dont understand what is happening!

Comment: Yikes. At this point, my only advice would be to try isolating the icons from each other by assigning IDs and trying to animate by referencing the IDs, or forcing the margins using and ID and an  `!important` tag on the margins. Sadly that's a rather dirty fix...